# Excel VBA - Two dimensional loop logic required through multiple sheets to achieve a copy / paste value if two dimensions match

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

For work I am developing a fully automated tool which can take an extract from our Financial Enterprise Tool (SAP) and bring the values across to a Financial Spreadsheet for reporting purposes. In order to achieve this, I have chosen to code a spreadsheet to take the extracted data from SAP, normalize it, and then shift it across to the financial Spreadsheet.

I am 3/4 of the way there, except I cannot work out how to get the data from the normalized data sheet (source) across to the financial spreadsheet (destination) due to the complex nature of how the data is laid out.

The source sheet which contains the SAP data is sorted as follows

**1. Column A - Rows 6 to 6000 - Contains the Names of people**

**2. Column A - AX - Row 5 - Contains the posting date**

**3. Column B6:AX6000 - Contains the financial data (NOTE, the range is not fixed, it is a dynamic / variable range)**

The target sheet which contains the financial data is sorted as follows

**1. Column E - Rows 528 to 1268 - Contains the Names of people**

**2. Column A - AX - Row 5 - Contains the posting date**

**3. Column H528:AX1260 - Contains the financial data (NOTE, this range IS fixed)**

What I would like the code to do, is look at the dates in the source and target spreadsheet. If it finds two matching date entries, then look through the names. If it finds a name match, then the corresponding financial figure against that name and the date should be bought across from the source cell to the target cell.  Once all the names have been scanned, then goto the next date on the source cell

This is what I am aiming for

```
Source: NOTE: Micks entry in Column C, Line 8
___|__A__||__B__| |__C__| |__D__|
 5 |Date | 01/01| |01/02| |01/03|
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
 6 |Jake |      | |     | |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
 7 |Mike |      | |     | |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
 8 |Mick |      | |$222 | |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|

Original Target:
___|__E__||__I__| |__J__| |__K__|
 5 |     | 01/01| |01/02| |01/03|
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
528|Jake |  $540| | $444| |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
529|Mike |  $423| | $282| |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
530|Mick |  $452| | $523| |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|

New Target: Note Micks entry in Column J, Row 530
___|__E__||__I__| |__J__| |__K__|
 5 |Date | 01/01| |01/02| |01/03|
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
528|Jake |  $540| | $444| |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
529|Mike |  $423| | $282| |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
530|Mick |  $452| | $222| |     |
---|-----|------|-|-----|-|-----|
```

I have tried the following code in order to make this happen, but it doesn't produce a result, and I am stuck, any suggestions to where I might be going wrong? I have used and slightly altered the ranges of Tims answer below, this answer is getting there but the mr and mc ranges end up returning no values.

Current code is as follows:

```
Sub Tester()
MapValues Worksheets("Source").Range("A5").CurrentRegion,     Worksheets("Target").Range("E528").CurrentRegion
End Sub

Sub MapValues(rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range)

Dim r As Long, c As Long
Dim mr As Range, mc As Range, srcCell As Range

For r = 2 To rngDest.Rows.Count
For c = 2 To rngDest.Columns.Count
    'match doesn't work on dates so using Find()
    Set mr = rngSource.Columns(1).Find(rngDest.Cells(r, 1).Value, _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set mc = rngSource.Rows(1).Find(rngDest.Cells(1, c).Value, _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not mr Is Nothing And Not mc Is Nothing Then
        'locate the matching cell in the source block
        Set srcCell = rngSource.Parent.Cells(mr.Row, mc.Column)
        'copying only if there's a value in "source"
        If Len(srcCell.Value) > 0 Then
            rngDest.Cells(r, c).Value = srcCell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next c
Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: In your example both Source and Target are identical, so it's difficult to tell what the "anything else" is which should be ignored.  What *doesn't* get copied ?  You can probably use formulas to do what you want, with a mix of INDEX() and MATCH() like http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/0106%202D%20lookup.shtml

Comment: Formulas in this case cannot be used, the layouts of the spreadsheet are the same in the example, but they are radically different and large.  Doing the Index / Match would eliminate the goal of completely scripted automation.

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: I have added the code which I have written to do the 2D array lookup

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simplistic example of a 2-D lookup:

```
Sub Tester()
    MapValues Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Range("A16").CurrentRegion
End Sub

Sub MapValues(rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range)

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim mr As Range, mc As Range, srcCell As Range

    For r = 2 To rngDest.Rows.Count
        For c = 2 To rngDest.Columns.Count
            'match doesn't work on dates so using Find()
            Set mr = rngSource.Columns(1).Find(rngDest.Cells(r, 1).Value, _
                                       LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            Set mc = rngSource.Rows(1).Find(rngDest.Cells(1, c).Value, _
                                       LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not mr Is Nothing And Not mc Is Nothing Then
                'locate the matching cell in the source block
                Set srcCell = rngSource.Parent.Cells(mr.Row, mc.Column)
                'copying only if there's a value in "source"
                If Len(srcCell.Value) > 0 Then
                    rngDest.Cells(r, c).Value = srcCell.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
End Sub
```

The "source" and "destination" ranges with "before" and "after" running the test procedure:

[image]

Comment: Your code works much better than mine but for some reason, the code doesn't execute the rngdest.cells(r,c).value = srccell.value line, this tells me the find is not finding any which it can copy. I have tried to step through it and analyse where the gap is and I think the lookup is not scanning both sheets in the right manner.  The name range is all contained in the same column (Column A in the source, Column E in the target).  The date ranges are spread across columns in Row 5 on both, it doesn't seem to pick up the values against the names and dates on the source.

Comment: I should also mention that the source data is a pivot table, will that affect the result?

Comment: I based my example on your posted sample tables.  It's hard to be specific about suggested changes without knowing your exact layout.

Comment: When I tested the code on my sheet, the two integers do not loop, instead they stay on one cell.  I will have a play around with it and see if I can get the integers to loop.  I am aiming to get it to loop through the rows first (dates), and cycle through the dates for each name to see if it can get a match on the target spreadsheet.  Your code has helped me get a head start which is awesome, thank you for your help!

Comment: I rephrased the question using your code as an example, I failed to point out that the ranges in the source spreadsheet and target spreadsheet are different.  The dates are practically in the same rows, but the name ranges are very different, the source spreadsheet is in Column A and starts at row 5, but the Target spreadsheet contains names in Column E, and starts at Row 528

Comment: I'm out of town and no access to a computer for next couple of weeks.  Hopefully someone else can help